# Rspec: what's the difference between "its" and "specify"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Let's say I have this code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "in the Users controller" do

      describe "submitting to the update action" do
        before { put user_path(user) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Instead of:

> specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }

Why couldn't I use:

> its { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }

Comment: they are aliases if I recall well

Comment: Because "its" is wrong. The correct is "it".

Comment: `Actually, "context" and "specify" are the aliases of "describe" and 
"it"`. http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/127187

Comment: @Zippie: So it seems like the decision to use "specify" instead of "it" is purely to increase readability.

Answer (score 2):

AS [Zippie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1279707/zippie), [Juliano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/973740/juliano), [apneadiving](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350087/apneadiving) have stated:

**specify** its an alias to **it**

**context** its an alias to **describe**

You can use form its(:method) { expectation } to call methods on subject:

```
let(:bar) { Bar.new }
subject { bar }

its(:foo) { should == 0 }
```

to test this

```
class Bar
  def foo
    0
  end
end
```